# Selecting an icon set not working in polymer designer

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

According to [this page](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/icons.html#using-polymers-built-in-icon-sets), you can specify an icon from a different icon set by separating th icon set and the icon with a colon. The example they give is `social:cake`, but that oesn't seem to work in Polymer Designer. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a (known) bug?

[image]

Comment: did you import social-icons.html

Comment: I'm trying to do so now, but any time I add new link in the code view, and switch back to design view, it gets removed. Even when I hit the save icon before switching to design view.

Comment: I think there's a bug related to imports not being preserved: https://github.com/Polymer/designer/issues/46

Comment: The extra icon sets should be added to the palette.